# How to gather all node modules in a single file

Tags: node.js

I have installed alot of node modules in different projects and they are kind of scattered around many folders it will be much convenient to have them all in one folder, is there a way?

Comment: So you want to avoid having redudant `node_modules`? You can start installing them globally, but I don't think it's the best way to maintainability. I'm having trouble understanding your objective. The title differs from the text.

Comment: It's not clear what you find objectionable about "alot [sic] of node modules in different projects".

Comment: I have different projects scattered around my storage and in many of them I have used node modules according to need but node does not stores all module in the same place the dependencies I install in a project are stored in that folder or directory so every time I am working on a project I have to one by one check if all the dependencies I need are installed or not, now if they were in the all in the same folder then I could simply view the package.json and know which of the node modules need installing.